# PHP Dynamically created Checkboxes not 'checking'

Tags: php, html

Trying to create a collapsible un-ordered list dynamically based on database values, everything seems to work except the checkboxes. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

PHP Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---<script src="jquery.aCollapTable.js"></script> --->

<script>
function prepareList() {
  $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
    .click( function(event) {
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
            $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
        }
        return false;
    })
    .addClass('collapsed')
    .children('ul').hide();
  };

  $(document).ready( function() {
      prepareList();
  });
  </script>


</head>
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "user";
 $password = "pass";
 $dbname = "dbname";


 //Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//echo "<div id='db_conn'>Connected to Database successfully</div>";

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT (API) FROM API ORDER BY API ASC");
$sql0 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT (API) FROM API ORDER BY API ASC");
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
//$query = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

//echo $query;

 echo "<body>";

 echo "<h1> PNCP APIs </h1>";
 echo "<form method='POST' action='' >";
 echo "<ul id='expList'>";
 while($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql0)){
        $aryRng[] = $results['API'];
    }
 for($i=0;$i<=$numRows;$i++){
     echo "<li>".$aryRng[$i]."<ul>";
     $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT SubAPI FROM API WHERE API = '$aryRng[$i]'");
     $numRows1 = mysqli_num_rows($sql1);
      while($results1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1)){
        $aryRng1[] = $results1['SubAPI'];
    }
     for($j=0; $j<=$numRows1 - 1;$j++){
          echo "<li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='".$aryRng1[$j]."' id='" .$aryRng1[$j]. "'>".$aryRng1[$j]."</li>";
     }
     $aryRng1 = array();
     mysqli_free_result($sql1);
     echo "</ul></li>";
 }
 echo "</ul>";
 echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>";
 echo "</form>";
 mysqli_close($conn);

 ?>

</html>
```

Output is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---<script src="jquery.aCollapTable.js"></script> --->

<script>
function prepareList() {
  $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
   .click( function(event) {
    if (this == event.target) {
     $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
     $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
    }
    return false;
   })
   .addClass('collapsed')
   .children('ul').hide();
  };
 
  $(document).ready( function() {
      prepareList();
  });
  </script>


</head>
<body><h1> PNCP APIs </h1><form method='POST' action='' ><ul id='expList'><li>Account<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Account Details
' id='Get Account Details
'>Get Account Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Account
' id='Create Account
'>Create Account
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Account
' id='Modify Account
'>Modify Account
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Primary Contact
' id='Get Primary Contact
'>Get Primary Contact
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Primary Contact
' id='Modify Primary Contact
'>Modify Primary Contact
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Technical Contact
' id='Get Technical Contact
'>Get Technical Contact
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Technical Contact
' id='Modify Technical Contact
'>Modify Technical Contact
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Node Details for Account
' id='Get Node Details for Account
'>Get Node Details for Account
</li></ul></li><li>Allocation APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Allocation Limits
' id='Get Allocation Limits
'>Get Allocation Limits
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Allocation Limits
' id='Modify Allocation Limits
'>Modify Allocation Limits
</li></ul></li><li>Bare Metal APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Bare Metal Devices (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of Bare Metal Devices (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of Bare Metal Devices (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Bare Metal Devices (By Node)' id='Get List of Bare Metal Devices (By Node)'>Get List of Bare Metal Devices (By Node)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Device Details
' id='Get Bare Metal Device Details
'>Get Bare Metal Device Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Bare Metal Device
' id='Modify Bare Metal Device
'>Modify Bare Metal Device
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Power On/Off Bare Metal Device' id='Power On/Off Bare Metal Device'>Power On/Off Bare Metal Device</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Reboot Bare Metal Device
' id='Reboot Bare Metal Device
'>Reboot Bare Metal Device
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Device Assignment' id='Get Bare Metal Device Assignment'>Get Bare Metal Device Assignment</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Device Assignment Details' id='Get Bare Metal Device Assignment Details'>Get Bare Metal Device Assignment Details</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Assign Bare Metal Device
' id='Assign Bare Metal Device
'>Assign Bare Metal Device
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Remove Bare Metal Device Assignment' id='Remove Bare Metal Device Assignment'>Remove Bare Metal Device Assignment</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Device Tags
' id='Get Bare Metal Device Tags
'>Get Bare Metal Device Tags
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Add Tag to Bare Metal Device
' id='Add Tag to Bare Metal Device
'>Add Tag to Bare Metal Device
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Remove Tag from Bare Metal Device' id='Remove Tag from Bare Metal Device'>Remove Tag from Bare Metal Device</li></ul></li><li>Bare Metal Firewall APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Bare Metal Firewalls (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of Bare Metal Firewalls (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of Bare Metal Firewalls (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Bare Metal Firewalls (By Node)' id='Get List of Bare Metal Firewalls (By Node)'>Get List of Bare Metal Firewalls (By Node)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Bare Metal Details' id='Get List of Bare Metal Details'>Get List of Bare Metal Details</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Bare Metal Firewall
' id='Modify Bare Metal Firewall
'>Modify Bare Metal Firewall
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Firewall Assignment' id='Get Bare Metal Firewall Assignment'>Get Bare Metal Firewall Assignment</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Firewall Assignment Details' id='Get Bare Metal Firewall Assignment Details'>Get Bare Metal Firewall Assignment Details</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Assign Bare Metal Firewall
' id='Assign Bare Metal Firewall
'>Assign Bare Metal Firewall
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Remove Bare Metal Firewall Assignment' id='Remove Bare Metal Firewall Assignment'>Remove Bare Metal Firewall Assignment</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Firewall Tags
' id='Get Bare Metal Firewall Tags
'>Get Bare Metal Firewall Tags
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Add Tag to Bare Metal Firewall' id='Add Tag to Bare Metal Firewall'>Add Tag to Bare Metal Firewall</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Remove Tag from Bare Metal Firewall' id='Remove Tag from Bare Metal Firewall'>Remove Tag from Bare Metal Firewall</li></ul></li><li>Billing APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Rated Usage
' id='Get Rated Usage
'>Get Rated Usage
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Node Rated Usage
' id='Get Node Rated Usage
'>Get Node Rated Usage
</li></ul></li><li>Devices APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Devices (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of Devices (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of Devices (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Devices (By Node)
' id='Get List of Devices (By Node)
'>Get List of Devices (By Node)
</li></ul></li><li>Disk Management APIs for Virtu<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Disks on Virtual Machine' id='Get List of Disks on Virtual Machine'>Get List of Disks on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Details of Disk on Virtual Machine' id='Get Details of Disk on Virtual Machine'>Get Details of Disk on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Add Secondary Disk to Virtual Machine' id='Add Secondary Disk to Virtual Machine'>Add Secondary Disk to Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Secondary Disk on Virtual Machine' id='Modify Secondary Disk on Virtual Machine'>Modify Secondary Disk on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Remove Secondary Disk from Virtual Machine' id='Remove Secondary Disk from Virtual Machine'>Remove Secondary Disk from Virtual Machine</li></ul></li><li>Firewall APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Firewall Details
' id='Get Firewall Details
'>Get Firewall Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Firewall
' id='Modify Firewall
'>Modify Firewall
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Firewall Status
' id='Modify Firewall Status
'>Modify Firewall Status
</li></ul></li><li>Health Monitor APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create HTTP Monitor
' id='Create HTTP Monitor
'>Create HTTP Monitor
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create HTTPS Monitor
' id='Create HTTPS Monitor
'>Create HTTPS Monitor
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create TCP Monitor
' id='Create TCP Monitor
'>Create TCP Monitor
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Health Monitors (By Account and Node)' id='Get List of Health Monitors (By Account and Node)'>Get List of Health Monitors (By Account and Node)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get HTTP Monitor Details
' id='Get HTTP Monitor Details
'>Get HTTP Monitor Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get HTTPS Monitor Details
' id='Get HTTPS Monitor Details
'>Get HTTPS Monitor Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get TCP Monitor Details
' id='Get TCP Monitor Details
'>Get TCP Monitor Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify HTTP Monitor
' id='Modify HTTP Monitor
'>Modify HTTP Monitor
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify HTTPS Monitor
' id='Modify HTTPS Monitor
'>Modify HTTPS Monitor
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify TCP Monitor
' id='Modify TCP Monitor
'>Modify TCP Monitor
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Delete Monitor
' id='Delete Monitor
'>Delete Monitor
</li></ul></li><li>Health Monitor Management APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Update Load Balancer Monitor Assignments' id='Update Load Balancer Monitor Assignments'>Update Load Balancer Monitor Assignments</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Assigned Monitors on Load Balancer' id='Get List of Assigned Monitors on Load Balancer'>Get List of Assigned Monitors on Load Balancer</li></ul></li><li>Image APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Image from Virtual Machine' id='Create Image from Virtual Machine'>Create Image from Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of All Images (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of All Images (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of All Images (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of All Images (By Nodes)' id='Get List of All Images (By Nodes)'>Get List of All Images (By Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Image Details
' id='Get Image Details
'>Get Image Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Download Image
' id='Download Image
'>Download Image
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Update Image Details
' id='Update Image Details
'>Update Image Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Delete Image
' id='Delete Image
'>Delete Image
</li></ul></li><li>IP Management APIs for Virtual<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Public IPs on Virtual Machine' id='Get List of Public IPs on Virtual Machine'>Get List of Public IPs on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Private IPs on Virtual Machine' id='Get List of Private IPs on Virtual Machine'>Get List of Private IPs on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Details of Public IP on Virtual Machine' id='Get Details of Public IP on Virtual Machine'>Get Details of Public IP on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Details of Private IP on Virtual Machine' id='Get Details of Private IP on Virtual Machine'>Get Details of Private IP on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Assign Public IP to Virtual Machine' id='Assign Public IP to Virtual Machine'>Assign Public IP to Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Assign Private IP to Virtual Machine' id='Assign Private IP to Virtual Machine'>Assign Private IP to Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Public IP on Virtual Machine' id='Modify Public IP on Virtual Machine'>Modify Public IP on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Private IP on Virtual Machine' id='Modify Private IP on Virtual Machine'>Modify Private IP on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Release Public IP from Virtual Machine' id='Release Public IP from Virtual Machine'>Release Public IP from Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Release Private IP from Virtual Machine' id='Release Private IP from Virtual Machine'>Release Private IP from Virtual Machine</li></ul></li><li>Load Balancer APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Load Balancer Pools (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of Load Balancer Pools (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of Load Balancer Pools (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Load Balancer Pools (By Node)' id='Get List of Load Balancer Pools (By Node)'>Get List of Load Balancer Pools (By Node)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Load Balancer Pool Details' id='Get Load Balancer Pool Details'>Get Load Balancer Pool Details</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Load Balancer Pool
' id='Create Load Balancer Pool
'>Create Load Balancer Pool
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Load Balancer Pool
' id='Modify Load Balancer Pool
'>Modify Load Balancer Pool
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Delete Load Balancer Pool
' id='Delete Load Balancer Pool
'>Delete Load Balancer Pool
</li></ul></li><li>Network Configuration APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Network Configuration
' id='Get Network Configuration
'>Get Network Configuration
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Network Configuration
' id='Modify Network Configuration
'>Modify Network Configuration
</li></ul></li><li>Network Storage APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Network Storage Volume
' id='Create Network Storage Volume
'>Create Network Storage Volume
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of All Network Storage Volumns (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of All Network Storage Volumns (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of All Network Storage Volumns (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Network Storage Volumn (By Node)' id='Get Network Storage Volumn (By Node)'>Get Network Storage Volumn (By Node)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Network Storage Volumn Details' id='Get Network Storage Volumn Details'>Get Network Storage Volumn Details</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Network Storage Volume
' id='Modify Network Storage Volume
'>Modify Network Storage Volume
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Delete Network Storage Volume
' id='Delete Network Storage Volume
'>Delete Network Storage Volume
</li></ul></li><li>Node APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Nodes (By Account)' id='Get List of Nodes (By Account)'>Get List of Nodes (By Account)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Node Details
' id='Get Node Details
'>Get Node Details
</li></ul></li><li>Operating System Templates  AP<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of OS Templates
' id='Get List of OS Templates
'>Get List of OS Templates
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get OS Template Details
' id='Get OS Template Details
'>Get OS Template Details
</li></ul></li><li>Orders APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Service Plans
' id='Get List of Service Plans
'>Get List of Service Plans
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Service Plan Details
' id='Get Service Plan Details
'>Get Service Plan Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Submit Order
' id='Submit Order
'>Submit Order
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Orders
' id='Get Orders
'>Get Orders
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Order Details
' id='Get Order Details
'>Get Order Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Cancel Order
' id='Cancel Order
'>Cancel Order
</li></ul></li><li>Pricing Profile APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Assigned Pricing Profile
' id='Get Assigned Pricing Profile
'>Get Assigned Pricing Profile
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Pricing Profiles
' id='Get List of Pricing Profiles
'>Get List of Pricing Profiles
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Accounts with Assigned Pricing Profile' id='Get List of Accounts with Assigned Pricing Profile'>Get List of Accounts with Assigned Pricing Profile</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Pricing Profile Details
' id='Get Pricing Profile Details
'>Get Pricing Profile Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Pricing Profile
' id='Create Pricing Profile
'>Create Pricing Profile
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Set Default Pricing Profile
' id='Set Default Pricing Profile
'>Set Default Pricing Profile
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Default Pricing
' id='Get Default Pricing
'>Get Default Pricing
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Assign Pricing Profile to Account' id='Assign Pricing Profile to Account'>Assign Pricing Profile to Account</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Add Node Pricing Profile to All Account Pricing Profiles' id='Add Node Pricing Profile to All Account Pricing Profiles'>Add Node Pricing Profile to All Account Pricing Profiles</li></ul></li><li>Provider APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify VLAN Deletion Indicator -FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY!!' id='Modify VLAN Deletion Indicator -FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY!!'>Modify VLAN Deletion Indicator -FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY!!</li></ul></li><li>Public IP Locator APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Public IPs (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of Public IPs (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of Public IPs (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Public IPs (By Node)' id='Get List of Public IPs (By Node)'>Get List of Public IPs (By Node)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Reserve Public IP
' id='Reserve Public IP
'>Reserve Public IP
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Public IP Details
' id='Get Public IP Details
'>Get Public IP Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Release Public IP
' id='Release Public IP
'>Release Public IP
</li></ul></li><li>Risk Mitigation APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Suspend/Unsuspend Users
' id='Suspend/Unsuspend Users
'>Suspend/Unsuspend Users
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Hold/Unhold Account
' id='Hold/Unhold Account
'>Hold/Unhold Account
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Cancel Account Request
' id='Cancel Account Request
'>Cancel Account Request
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Reactivate Account
' id='Reactivate Account
'>Reactivate Account
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Terminate Account
' id='Terminate Account
'>Terminate Account
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Enable/Disable Network for a Virtual Machine' id='Enable/Disable Network for a Virtual Machine'>Enable/Disable Network for a Virtual Machine</li></ul></li><li>Service APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Services (By Account)' id='Get List of Services (By Account)'>Get List of Services (By Account)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Service Details
' id='Get Service Details
'>Get Service Details
</li></ul></li><li>Tags & Multi Select APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Tags
' id='Get List of Tags
'>Get List of Tags
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Tag
' id='Create Tag
'>Create Tag
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Tag Name
' id='Modify Tag Name
'>Modify Tag Name
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Delete Tag
' id='Delete Tag
'>Delete Tag
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Tagged Devices
' id='Get Tagged Devices
'>Get Tagged Devices
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Multi Select: Change Power State' id='Multi Select: Change Power State'>Multi Select: Change Power State</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Multi Select: Clone VMs
' id='Multi Select: Clone VMs
'>Multi Select: Clone VMs
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Multi Select: Export VMs
' id='Multi Select: Export VMs
'>Multi Select: Export VMs
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Multi Select: Delete VMs
' id='Multi Select: Delete VMs
'>Multi Select: Delete VMs
</li></ul></li><li>Task APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Task Status
' id='Get Task Status
'>Get Task Status
</li></ul></li><li>User Account APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of User Accounts
' id='Get List of User Accounts
'>Get List of User Accounts
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get User Account Details
' id='Get User Account Details
'>Get User Account Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create User Account
' id='Create User Account
'>Create User Account
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify User Account
' id='Modify User Account
'>Modify User Account
</li></ul></li><li>Virtual Machine APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Virtual Machines (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of Virtual Machines (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of Virtual Machines (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Virtual Machines (By Nodes)' id='Get List of Virtual Machines (By Nodes)'>Get List of Virtual Machines (By Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Virtual Machine Details
' id='Get Virtual Machine Details
'>Get Virtual Machine Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Virtual Machine
' id='Create Virtual Machine
'>Create Virtual Machine
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Power On / Off Virtual Machine' id='Power On / Off Virtual Machine'>Power On / Off Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Reboot Virtual Machine
' id='Reboot Virtual Machine
'>Reboot Virtual Machine
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Clone Virtual Machine
' id='Clone Virtual Machine
'>Clone Virtual Machine
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Virtual Machine
' id='Modify Virtual Machine
'>Modify Virtual Machine
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Delete Virtual Machine
' id='Delete Virtual Machine
'>Delete Virtual Machine
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Virtual Machine Tags
' id='Get Virtual Machine Tags
'>Get Virtual Machine Tags
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Add Tag to Virtual Machine
' id='Add Tag to Virtual Machine
'>Add Tag to Virtual Machine
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Remove Tag from Virtual Machine' id='Remove Tag from Virtual Machine'>Remove Tag from Virtual Machine</li></ul></li><li><ul></ul></li></ul><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/></form>
</html>
```

My Problem is that none of the 'checkboxes' work. I cannot 'check' any of them. I been trying to figure this out for hours. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: "*I cannot 'check' any of them*" So if you put your cursor over the checkbox, click it, nothing happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the input checkbox, li click event is also triggered and your javascript return false causing checking action cancellation.

Use only "return" instead of "return false". Or don't return anything since it doesn't matter in your javascript function.

EDIT: Modified "working" code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---<script src="jquery.aCollapTable.js"></script> --->

<script>
function prepareList() {
  $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
   .click( function(event) {
    if (this == event.target) {
     $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
     $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
    }
   })
   .addClass('collapsed')
   .children('ul').hide();
  };
 
  $(document).ready( function() {
      prepareList();
  });
  </script>


</head>
<body><h1> PNCP APIs </h1><form method='POST' action='' ><ul id='expList'><li>Account<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Account Details
' id='Get Account Details
'>Get Account Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Account
' id='Create Account
'>Create Account
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Account
' id='Modify Account
'>Modify Account
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Primary Contact
' id='Get Primary Contact
'>Get Primary Contact
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Primary Contact
' id='Modify Primary Contact
'>Modify Primary Contact
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Technical Contact
' id='Get Technical Contact
'>Get Technical Contact
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Technical Contact
' id='Modify Technical Contact
'>Modify Technical Contact
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Node Details for Account
' id='Get Node Details for Account
'>Get Node Details for Account
</li></ul></li><li>Allocation APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Allocation Limits
' id='Get Allocation Limits
'>Get Allocation Limits
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Allocation Limits
' id='Modify Allocation Limits
'>Modify Allocation Limits
</li></ul></li><li>Bare Metal APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Bare Metal Devices (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of Bare Metal Devices (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of Bare Metal Devices (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Bare Metal Devices (By Node)' id='Get List of Bare Metal Devices (By Node)'>Get List of Bare Metal Devices (By Node)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Device Details
' id='Get Bare Metal Device Details
'>Get Bare Metal Device Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Bare Metal Device
' id='Modify Bare Metal Device
'>Modify Bare Metal Device
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Power On/Off Bare Metal Device' id='Power On/Off Bare Metal Device'>Power On/Off Bare Metal Device</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Reboot Bare Metal Device
' id='Reboot Bare Metal Device
'>Reboot Bare Metal Device
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Device Assignment' id='Get Bare Metal Device Assignment'>Get Bare Metal Device Assignment</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Device Assignment Details' id='Get Bare Metal Device Assignment Details'>Get Bare Metal Device Assignment Details</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Assign Bare Metal Device
' id='Assign Bare Metal Device
'>Assign Bare Metal Device
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Remove Bare Metal Device Assignment' id='Remove Bare Metal Device Assignment'>Remove Bare Metal Device Assignment</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Device Tags
' id='Get Bare Metal Device Tags
'>Get Bare Metal Device Tags
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Add Tag to Bare Metal Device
' id='Add Tag to Bare Metal Device
'>Add Tag to Bare Metal Device
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Remove Tag from Bare Metal Device' id='Remove Tag from Bare Metal Device'>Remove Tag from Bare Metal Device</li></ul></li><li>Bare Metal Firewall APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Bare Metal Firewalls (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of Bare Metal Firewalls (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of Bare Metal Firewalls (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Bare Metal Firewalls (By Node)' id='Get List of Bare Metal Firewalls (By Node)'>Get List of Bare Metal Firewalls (By Node)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Bare Metal Details' id='Get List of Bare Metal Details'>Get List of Bare Metal Details</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Bare Metal Firewall
' id='Modify Bare Metal Firewall
'>Modify Bare Metal Firewall
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Firewall Assignment' id='Get Bare Metal Firewall Assignment'>Get Bare Metal Firewall Assignment</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Firewall Assignment Details' id='Get Bare Metal Firewall Assignment Details'>Get Bare Metal Firewall Assignment Details</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Assign Bare Metal Firewall
' id='Assign Bare Metal Firewall
'>Assign Bare Metal Firewall
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Remove Bare Metal Firewall Assignment' id='Remove Bare Metal Firewall Assignment'>Remove Bare Metal Firewall Assignment</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Bare Metal Firewall Tags
' id='Get Bare Metal Firewall Tags
'>Get Bare Metal Firewall Tags
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Add Tag to Bare Metal Firewall' id='Add Tag to Bare Metal Firewall'>Add Tag to Bare Metal Firewall</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Remove Tag from Bare Metal Firewall' id='Remove Tag from Bare Metal Firewall'>Remove Tag from Bare Metal Firewall</li></ul></li><li>Billing APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Rated Usage
' id='Get Rated Usage
'>Get Rated Usage
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Node Rated Usage
' id='Get Node Rated Usage
'>Get Node Rated Usage
</li></ul></li><li>Devices APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Devices (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of Devices (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of Devices (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Devices (By Node)
' id='Get List of Devices (By Node)
'>Get List of Devices (By Node)
</li></ul></li><li>Disk Management APIs for Virtu<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Disks on Virtual Machine' id='Get List of Disks on Virtual Machine'>Get List of Disks on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Details of Disk on Virtual Machine' id='Get Details of Disk on Virtual Machine'>Get Details of Disk on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Add Secondary Disk to Virtual Machine' id='Add Secondary Disk to Virtual Machine'>Add Secondary Disk to Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Secondary Disk on Virtual Machine' id='Modify Secondary Disk on Virtual Machine'>Modify Secondary Disk on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Remove Secondary Disk from Virtual Machine' id='Remove Secondary Disk from Virtual Machine'>Remove Secondary Disk from Virtual Machine</li></ul></li><li>Firewall APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Firewall Details
' id='Get Firewall Details
'>Get Firewall Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Firewall
' id='Modify Firewall
'>Modify Firewall
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Firewall Status
' id='Modify Firewall Status
'>Modify Firewall Status
</li></ul></li><li>Health Monitor APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create HTTP Monitor
' id='Create HTTP Monitor
'>Create HTTP Monitor
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create HTTPS Monitor
' id='Create HTTPS Monitor
'>Create HTTPS Monitor
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create TCP Monitor
' id='Create TCP Monitor
'>Create TCP Monitor
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Health Monitors (By Account and Node)' id='Get List of Health Monitors (By Account and Node)'>Get List of Health Monitors (By Account and Node)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get HTTP Monitor Details
' id='Get HTTP Monitor Details
'>Get HTTP Monitor Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get HTTPS Monitor Details
' id='Get HTTPS Monitor Details
'>Get HTTPS Monitor Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get TCP Monitor Details
' id='Get TCP Monitor Details
'>Get TCP Monitor Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify HTTP Monitor
' id='Modify HTTP Monitor
'>Modify HTTP Monitor
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify HTTPS Monitor
' id='Modify HTTPS Monitor
'>Modify HTTPS Monitor
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify TCP Monitor
' id='Modify TCP Monitor
'>Modify TCP Monitor
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Delete Monitor
' id='Delete Monitor
'>Delete Monitor
</li></ul></li><li>Health Monitor Management APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Update Load Balancer Monitor Assignments' id='Update Load Balancer Monitor Assignments'>Update Load Balancer Monitor Assignments</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Assigned Monitors on Load Balancer' id='Get List of Assigned Monitors on Load Balancer'>Get List of Assigned Monitors on Load Balancer</li></ul></li><li>Image APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Image from Virtual Machine' id='Create Image from Virtual Machine'>Create Image from Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of All Images (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of All Images (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of All Images (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of All Images (By Nodes)' id='Get List of All Images (By Nodes)'>Get List of All Images (By Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Image Details
' id='Get Image Details
'>Get Image Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Download Image
' id='Download Image
'>Download Image
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Update Image Details
' id='Update Image Details
'>Update Image Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Delete Image
' id='Delete Image
'>Delete Image
</li></ul></li><li>IP Management APIs for Virtual<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Public IPs on Virtual Machine' id='Get List of Public IPs on Virtual Machine'>Get List of Public IPs on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Private IPs on Virtual Machine' id='Get List of Private IPs on Virtual Machine'>Get List of Private IPs on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Details of Public IP on Virtual Machine' id='Get Details of Public IP on Virtual Machine'>Get Details of Public IP on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Details of Private IP on Virtual Machine' id='Get Details of Private IP on Virtual Machine'>Get Details of Private IP on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Assign Public IP to Virtual Machine' id='Assign Public IP to Virtual Machine'>Assign Public IP to Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Assign Private IP to Virtual Machine' id='Assign Private IP to Virtual Machine'>Assign Private IP to Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Public IP on Virtual Machine' id='Modify Public IP on Virtual Machine'>Modify Public IP on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Private IP on Virtual Machine' id='Modify Private IP on Virtual Machine'>Modify Private IP on Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Release Public IP from Virtual Machine' id='Release Public IP from Virtual Machine'>Release Public IP from Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Release Private IP from Virtual Machine' id='Release Private IP from Virtual Machine'>Release Private IP from Virtual Machine</li></ul></li><li>Load Balancer APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Load Balancer Pools (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of Load Balancer Pools (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of Load Balancer Pools (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Load Balancer Pools (By Node)' id='Get List of Load Balancer Pools (By Node)'>Get List of Load Balancer Pools (By Node)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Load Balancer Pool Details' id='Get Load Balancer Pool Details'>Get Load Balancer Pool Details</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Load Balancer Pool
' id='Create Load Balancer Pool
'>Create Load Balancer Pool
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Load Balancer Pool
' id='Modify Load Balancer Pool
'>Modify Load Balancer Pool
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Delete Load Balancer Pool
' id='Delete Load Balancer Pool
'>Delete Load Balancer Pool
</li></ul></li><li>Network Configuration APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Network Configuration
' id='Get Network Configuration
'>Get Network Configuration
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Network Configuration
' id='Modify Network Configuration
'>Modify Network Configuration
</li></ul></li><li>Network Storage APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Network Storage Volume
' id='Create Network Storage Volume
'>Create Network Storage Volume
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of All Network Storage Volumns (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of All Network Storage Volumns (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of All Network Storage Volumns (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Network Storage Volumn (By Node)' id='Get Network Storage Volumn (By Node)'>Get Network Storage Volumn (By Node)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Network Storage Volumn Details' id='Get Network Storage Volumn Details'>Get Network Storage Volumn Details</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Network Storage Volume
' id='Modify Network Storage Volume
'>Modify Network Storage Volume
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Delete Network Storage Volume
' id='Delete Network Storage Volume
'>Delete Network Storage Volume
</li></ul></li><li>Node APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Nodes (By Account)' id='Get List of Nodes (By Account)'>Get List of Nodes (By Account)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Node Details
' id='Get Node Details
'>Get Node Details
</li></ul></li><li>Operating System Templates  AP<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of OS Templates
' id='Get List of OS Templates
'>Get List of OS Templates
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get OS Template Details
' id='Get OS Template Details
'>Get OS Template Details
</li></ul></li><li>Orders APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Service Plans
' id='Get List of Service Plans
'>Get List of Service Plans
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Service Plan Details
' id='Get Service Plan Details
'>Get Service Plan Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Submit Order
' id='Submit Order
'>Submit Order
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Orders
' id='Get Orders
'>Get Orders
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Order Details
' id='Get Order Details
'>Get Order Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Cancel Order
' id='Cancel Order
'>Cancel Order
</li></ul></li><li>Pricing Profile APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Assigned Pricing Profile
' id='Get Assigned Pricing Profile
'>Get Assigned Pricing Profile
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Pricing Profiles
' id='Get List of Pricing Profiles
'>Get List of Pricing Profiles
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Accounts with Assigned Pricing Profile' id='Get List of Accounts with Assigned Pricing Profile'>Get List of Accounts with Assigned Pricing Profile</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Pricing Profile Details
' id='Get Pricing Profile Details
'>Get Pricing Profile Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Pricing Profile
' id='Create Pricing Profile
'>Create Pricing Profile
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Set Default Pricing Profile
' id='Set Default Pricing Profile
'>Set Default Pricing Profile
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Default Pricing
' id='Get Default Pricing
'>Get Default Pricing
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Assign Pricing Profile to Account' id='Assign Pricing Profile to Account'>Assign Pricing Profile to Account</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Add Node Pricing Profile to All Account Pricing Profiles' id='Add Node Pricing Profile to All Account Pricing Profiles'>Add Node Pricing Profile to All Account Pricing Profiles</li></ul></li><li>Provider APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify VLAN Deletion Indicator -FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY!!' id='Modify VLAN Deletion Indicator -FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY!!'>Modify VLAN Deletion Indicator -FOR INTERNAL USE ONLY!!</li></ul></li><li>Public IP Locator APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Public IPs (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of Public IPs (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of Public IPs (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Public IPs (By Node)' id='Get List of Public IPs (By Node)'>Get List of Public IPs (By Node)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Reserve Public IP
' id='Reserve Public IP
'>Reserve Public IP
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Public IP Details
' id='Get Public IP Details
'>Get Public IP Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Release Public IP
' id='Release Public IP
'>Release Public IP
</li></ul></li><li>Risk Mitigation APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Suspend/Unsuspend Users
' id='Suspend/Unsuspend Users
'>Suspend/Unsuspend Users
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Hold/Unhold Account
' id='Hold/Unhold Account
'>Hold/Unhold Account
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Cancel Account Request
' id='Cancel Account Request
'>Cancel Account Request
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Reactivate Account
' id='Reactivate Account
'>Reactivate Account
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Terminate Account
' id='Terminate Account
'>Terminate Account
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Enable/Disable Network for a Virtual Machine' id='Enable/Disable Network for a Virtual Machine'>Enable/Disable Network for a Virtual Machine</li></ul></li><li>Service APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Services (By Account)' id='Get List of Services (By Account)'>Get List of Services (By Account)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Service Details
' id='Get Service Details
'>Get Service Details
</li></ul></li><li>Tags & Multi Select APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Tags
' id='Get List of Tags
'>Get List of Tags
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Tag
' id='Create Tag
'>Create Tag
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Tag Name
' id='Modify Tag Name
'>Modify Tag Name
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Delete Tag
' id='Delete Tag
'>Delete Tag
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Tagged Devices
' id='Get Tagged Devices
'>Get Tagged Devices
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Multi Select: Change Power State' id='Multi Select: Change Power State'>Multi Select: Change Power State</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Multi Select: Clone VMs
' id='Multi Select: Clone VMs
'>Multi Select: Clone VMs
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Multi Select: Export VMs
' id='Multi Select: Export VMs
'>Multi Select: Export VMs
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Multi Select: Delete VMs
' id='Multi Select: Delete VMs
'>Multi Select: Delete VMs
</li></ul></li><li>Task APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Task Status
' id='Get Task Status
'>Get Task Status
</li></ul></li><li>User Account APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of User Accounts
' id='Get List of User Accounts
'>Get List of User Accounts
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get User Account Details
' id='Get User Account Details
'>Get User Account Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create User Account
' id='Create User Account
'>Create User Account
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify User Account
' id='Modify User Account
'>Modify User Account
</li></ul></li><li>Virtual Machine APIs<ul><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Virtual Machines (By Account -All Nodes)' id='Get List of Virtual Machines (By Account -All Nodes)'>Get List of Virtual Machines (By Account -All Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get List of Virtual Machines (By Nodes)' id='Get List of Virtual Machines (By Nodes)'>Get List of Virtual Machines (By Nodes)</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Virtual Machine Details
' id='Get Virtual Machine Details
'>Get Virtual Machine Details
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Create Virtual Machine
' id='Create Virtual Machine
'>Create Virtual Machine
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Power On / Off Virtual Machine' id='Power On / Off Virtual Machine'>Power On / Off Virtual Machine</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Reboot Virtual Machine
' id='Reboot Virtual Machine
'>Reboot Virtual Machine
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Clone Virtual Machine
' id='Clone Virtual Machine
'>Clone Virtual Machine
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Modify Virtual Machine
' id='Modify Virtual Machine
'>Modify Virtual Machine
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Delete Virtual Machine
' id='Delete Virtual Machine
'>Delete Virtual Machine
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Get Virtual Machine Tags
' id='Get Virtual Machine Tags
'>Get Virtual Machine Tags
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Add Tag to Virtual Machine
' id='Add Tag to Virtual Machine
'>Add Tag to Virtual Machine
</li><li><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='Remove Tag from Virtual Machine' id='Remove Tag from Virtual Machine'>Remove Tag from Virtual Machine</li></ul></li><li><ul></ul></li></ul><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/></form>
</html>
```

Comment: That was the problem, everything working. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it helps!